# Allow application to control computer (assistive devices) on Mavericks via Terminal?

Tags: terminal, macos, applescript, plist, automation

I'm currently working on automated instalation of Mavericks 10.9. I have NetBoot set up. Everything works OK untill I want to execute Applescript. Since the release of new version I need to manually enable those scripts. Is there a command that I can use in shell script to add app to Assistive Devices list? Or maybe there is some plist that has to be edited for it to work?

Comment: I'm not totally sure this is what you're seeing, but this article might help: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5914

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I also stumbled on this article while I was searching for solution. It is not what I am looking for as this solution still uses GUI interaction.

Comment: @KarolBerlinski What was the workaround you used? I am still trying to figure out how to add an app to the Assistive Devices via command line or a non GUI method. Thanks
Abraham

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The settings are stored in `/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db`:

```
$ sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db 'select * from access'
kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.apple.ScriptEditor2|0|1|0|��

kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.red-sweater.FastScripts|0|1|0|��

kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.apple.AccessibilityInspector|0|1|0|��

kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.slate.Slate|0|1|0|��

kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.apple.Automator|0|1|1|
kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.googlecode.iterm2|0|1|1|
```

The schema, as given by `sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db '.schema access'`, is:

```
CREATE TABLE access (service TEXT NOT NULL, client TEXT NOT NULL, client_type INTEGER NOT NULL, allowed INTEGER NOT NULL, prompt_count INTEGER NOT NULL, csreq BLOB, CONSTRAINT key PRIMARY KEY (service, client, client_type));
```

On my installation the last four columns (`client_type`, `allowed`, `prompt_count`, and `csreq`) are `0|1|0|\xfa\xde\x0c` for applications that were added after the `"example.app" would like to control this computer using accessibility features` dialog was shown and `0|1|1|` for applications that I added by dropping them to the list in System Preferences.

`~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning.plist` contains a list of applications for which the warning dialog has been shown:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning
{
    "/Applications/Automator.app" = 1;
    "/Applications/Automator.app/Contents/MacOS/Automator" = 1;
    "/Applications/FastScripts.app" = 1;
    "/Applications/FastScripts.app/Contents/MacOS/FastScripts" = 1;
    "/Applications/Slate.app" = 1;
    "/Applications/Slate.app/Contents/MacOS/Slate" = 1;
    "/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor.app" = 1;
    "/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor.app/Contents/MacOS/AppleScript Editor" = 1;
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Accessibility Inspector.app" = 1;
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Accessibility Inspector.app/Contents/MacOS/Accessibility Inspector" = 1;
    "/Applications/iTerm.app" = 1;
    "/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm" = 1;
    "/Users/lauri/Desktop/aa.app" = 1;
    "/Users/lauri/Desktop/aa.app/Contents/MacOS/applet" = 1;
    "com.apple.AccessibilityInspector" = 1;
    "com.apple.Automator" = 1;
    "com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.aa" = 1;
    "com.apple.ScriptEditor2" = 1;
    "com.red-sweater.FastScripts" = 1;
    "com.slate.Slate" = 1;
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to actually allow access for assistive devices for an application though. I tried for example running these commands:

```
sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db 'insert into access values ("kTCCServiceAccessibility","com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.qq",0,1,0,"'$'\xfa\xde\x0c''");'
defaults write com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.qq -bool true
defaults write com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning /Users/lauri/Desktop/qq.app -bool true
defaults write com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning /Users/lauri/Desktop/qq.app/Contents/MacOS/applet -bool true
sudo killall tccd
```

I also tried restarting to apply the changes and setting the last four columns to `0,1,1,""`.

Comment: Thank so much for your feedback. I was able to make a workaround thanks to it. 
The tccd proccess cannot be killed, only restart will be sufficient here. I start the app that needs Accesssibility, then use sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db 'update access set allowed=1' and then reboot system. It works. Thanks again (If you need access for one app from list you can add WHERE clause to your sql).

Comment: +1 for great sleuthing. See [AbsterT's answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/122405/28668) for a working programmatic based on `sudo sqlite3 ...`. `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning.plist` is not involved in _granting_ permissions, it only records whether a warning has been shown to avoid annoying users with repeated warnings.

Comment: The `??` (`\xfa\xde\x0c`) value stems from the `csreq` column, which contains a fingerprint of sorts of the specified app; OSX manages that automatically behind the scenes - no need to ever specify it. The actual value is much longer; the truncation to 3 bytes comes from trying to output the binary value (data type `BLOB`) as if it were a string, causing output to stop at the first NUL byte (the `?` stem from the `\xfa` and `\xde` not being valid characters in UTF8 encoding, `\x0c` is a vertical tab that effectively creates a line break).

Comment: The `csreq` column contains the compiled designated requirements for the app, see http://goo.gl/z10vl and Apple’s TN2206 _Code Signing in Depth_ guide. The designated requirements are essentially a script that validates an app’s identity by checking the bundle ID and certificates.

Comment: This technique seems to be used by Dropbox to add Accessibility entitlements without user involvement: http://applehelpwriter.com/2016/08/29/discovering-how-dropbox-hacks-your-mac/

Answer (score 8):

You can also add the file by following the commands below.

This command will find the Bundle Identifier for the application you are trying to add to Assistive Devices.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print CFBundleIdentifier' /Applications/enterapplicaitonnamehere.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Let's say the application you were trying to add was SKYPE.  You would then enter this below:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print CFBundleIdentifier' /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

And your bundle identifier would be :

```
com.skype.skype
```

You then use this output in the command below:

```
sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "REPLACE INTO access VALUES('kTCCServiceAccessibility','',0,1,1,NULL);"
```

For Skype it would look like this:

```
sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "REPLACE INTO access VALUES('kTCCServiceAccessibility','com.skype.skype',0,1,1,NULL);"
```

To remove the application you would use the `sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "delete from access where client='com.skype.skype';"`

Comment: +1, but for robustness it is better to use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO` so as to ensure that the command works even if the database already has an entry for the specified application.

Comment: @mklement Would that add the application if the application did not already exist in the database?

Comment: Yes, it would (`REPLACE INTO` is an alias for the more descriptive `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO`).

Comment: The REPLACE INTO is working perfectly and better than the INSERT INTO.

Comment: Does this method work for executable binaries that are inside a .prefpane Bundle?

Comment: For El Capitan the access table seems to have 7 columns instead of 6. I needed to add an extra NULL to the list of parameters.