# Add item to Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility

Tags: macos, vmware, firefox, adobe-flash

I am trying to give a flash application access to accessibility features.  The plug in lives in Macintosh HD > Library > Internet Plug-ins.  I cannot drag and drop this into the Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility.  Adding firefox app doesnt seem to work even though the plug in seems like it should be a child process.  In activity monitor when the particular flash app is running the process name is "Firefox Plugin Process (Shockwave Flash)".

How do I enable this?  How can I add items in the Accessibility menu without having to drag and drop?

Using OS X Mavericks 10.9.

Comment: Is this on Mavericks ?

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container.app` to the preference pane instead.

When I tried opening a page that uses Flash in Firefox, `ps -ef|grep -i flash` contained a line like `501 28715 28710   0  4:44AM ??         0:01.01 /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container.app/Contents/MacOS/plugin-container /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Flash Player.plugin -greomni /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/omni.ja -appomni /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/browser/omni.ja -appdir /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/browser 28710 gecko-crash-server-pipe.28710 org.mozilla.machname.157869410 plugin`.

If others search for how to add applications to the list with a script, see [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111903](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111903).